# If Object is the base of all classes, what is Object's base class?

Tags: .net

In .NET we know that all classes inherit from System.Object. This begs the question as to whether Object inherits from itself, or if it breaks the rule by not inheriting from any base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Object` does not have any base class, as described in the CLR specification:

**I.8.9.9 Object type inheritance**

> With the sole exception of  System.Object , which does not inherit
>   from any other object type, all object types shall either explicitly
>   or implicitly declare support for (i.e., inherit from) exactly one
>   other object type